# Set different Css3 transitions speed on a div and its children

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, css-transitions, css-animations

I try to implement Slidejs on my website. 
Here is the link of the [library](http://www.slidesjs.com/).

What I would like to do is setting a different speed transition in function of element.
Here is my Html structure :

```
<div id="slides" class="sliders_1">
    <div style="background:url(/images/slider/slide1.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center; background-size:100% auto;">
        <div class="slider-title">
            <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-subtitle">
            <h3 class="subtitle">Subtitle.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:url(/images/slider/slide1.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center; background-size:100% auto;">
        <div class="slider-title">
            <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-subtitle">
            <h3 class="subtitle">Subtitle.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For exemple, the slide effect can take 500ms for the background but I would like my h2 and h3 to have a different speed.
H2 : 600ms and h3 :300ms for example.

Hope I'm clear :)

**Update #1**
Here is my javascript :

```
$('.sliders_1').slidesjs({
    width: 940,
    height: 588
});
```

That's all I need to enable the library.

**Update #2**
To be more specific, I would like to slide the div with the background-image firstly.
During the first transition, can I launch another transition to both h2 and h3 with a different speed to each ?

**Update #3**
Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YrCd6/) !
What I would like to do works on Firefox but not on Safari, Chrome and others...
The slide speed between the background, h2 and h3 are different and that's what I want.

I would like it to slide from right to left !

Comment: Could you please provide your code...? So we can fix it shortly.

Comment: What do you need a part of current elements ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Please see update #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fadeSpeed (number)-Default is 350 milliseconds.**

Set the speed of the fading animation in milliseconds.

```
$(function(){
      $("#slides").slides({
        fadeSpeed: 350
      });
    });
```

**slideSpeed (number)-Default is 350 milliseconds.**

Set the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds.

```
$(function(){
      $("#slides").slides({
        slideSpeed: 350
      });
    });
```